# Find/replace character+line feed

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to search for character+line feed with regex?

For example to turn this:

```
line one
line two
line (three)
line four
line five
```

into this:

```
line one
line two
line (three)=line four
line five
```

e.g. to search for `)` and `\n` and replace `\n` only in lines containing `)` with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `\)\r?\n`, replace with `\)=`.

You need to escape special regex characters (like brackets) when using them as literal portions of your pattern. Here is a good read on that: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html